# What hand-made drink do you have during workouts?

Tags: energy-drinks

So far I've been having a large plastic bottle of fresh water that (1) had pieces of fresh strawberries during the night and (2) contains a few spoons of sugar. Not bad but takes a bit of time to prepare and doesn't have tons of flavor either. I'm sure some people out there have similar but better stuff. Any suggestion?

Comment: Asking for suggestions and the like are off topic except on a very few SE sites.

Comment: @JohnP, oh, come on. How is this not "nutrition as it relates to exercise" related...?

Comment: @uwnojpjm - From the [help center](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) on what not to ask, the top two points are: "To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …

    every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
    your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”"

Comment: @JohnP, this thesis is very antiquated in my opinion. It presumes the world's individual questions are answerable with only one answer. As "logical" and "reasonable" as the people are on this site, I would've thought they'd've seen this hypocrisy. Of all questions most have multiple answers. What kind of world is this that one answer is allowable, when, inconsistently, most questions have multiple answers already across all sites? Very meta, I know, right?

Comment: You do get, John, that upvoted non-accepted answers are still "equally valid" to those voters who didn't vote for the accepted answer, right?

Comment: @uwnojpjm you are certainly welcome to raise the question on the overall SE meta. That is the standard on almost all the SE sites.